# Assign one json value for two fields in java using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I am trying to assign the value returned by some function to a field in the deserialized class of json.

**FileInfo.java**

```
public class FileInfo {

  @SerializedName("Name")
  private String mName;

  @SerializedName("Url")
  private String mUri;

  @SerializedName("Size")
  private Integer mSize;

  @SerializedName("ModTime")
  private Long mModifiedTime;

  private FileType mType;

  @SerializedName("Children")
  private ArrayList<FileInfo> mChildren = new ArrayList<>();

  public ArrayList<FileInfo> getChildren() {
    return mChildren;
  }

  public long getModifiedTime() {
    return mModifiedTime;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return mName;
  }

  public Integer getSize() {
    return mSize;
  }

  public String getUrl() {
    return mUri;
  }

  public FileType getType() {
    return mType;
  }
  public void setChildren(ArrayList<FileInfo> mChildren) {
    this.mChildren = mChildren;
  }

  public void setModifiedTime(long mModifiedTime) {
    this.mModifiedTime = mModifiedTime;
  }

  public void setName(String mName) {
    this.mName = mName;
  }

  public void setSize(Integer mSize) {
    this.mSize = mSize;
  }

  public void setType(FileType mType) {
    this.mType = mType;
  }

  public void setUri(String mUri) {
    this.mUri = mUri;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return FileInfo.class.toString();
  }

  public FileInfo() {
  }
}
```

The **mType** needs to be assigned to **foo(mName)**. I looked up custom deserializers and instance creators but none of those helped. I also thought of TypeAdapters which i feel defeats the purpose of keeping deserialization(using GSON) simple.

This is a sample **JSON** string that will be deserialized.

```
[
{
      "Name":"Airport",
      "Url":"http://192.168.2.2/api/sites/Baltimore%20Airport/Airport",
      "Size":0,
      "ModTime":"2015-12-02T14:19:17.29824-05:00",
      "Children":null
   }
]
```

P.S. I'm not sure if this should be done during deserialization but trying anyways. Also please let me know of alternative ways to achieve this.

Comment: We can create a method and call it to populate mType once the request is deserialized.

Comment: How do you know when the deserialization for each node completes? Also, no that this is a tree kind of deserialization where each FileInfo will have list of children each of type FileInfo.

Comment: Well, objectMapper.readValue(..) or whichever method is used to deserialise the request returns object of FileInfo class, we can then call the new method to set mType field.

Comment: The thing is, if i use a custom deserializer for FileInfo class, i would have to read as a JsonObeject by and assign its values to each of the fields. Of course this would solve the problem but defeats the purpose of using GSON. This i want to avoid.